# Navigation to Homescreen not working after successful authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm building an authentication system with expo google sign in with Firebase. The react native application is supposed to navigate to the HomeScreen after successful authentication. The users' google authentication response is added to Firebase correctly but the application redirects to the LogInScreen instead of navigating to the Homescreen. Kindly assist.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';
import {firebase} from '../../firebase/config'

const LogInScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const isUserEqual =(googleUser, firebaseUser)=> {
    if (firebaseUser) {
      var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData;
      for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
          if (providerData[i].providerId === firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
             providerData[i].uid === googleUser.user.id) {
             return true;
          }
        }}
    }
    return false;
  }
  

  const onSignIn = (googleUser) => {
    console.log('Google Auth Response', googleUser);
    // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
      function(firebaseUser) {
        unsubscribe();
        // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
        if (!isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
          // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
          var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            googleUser.idToken,
            googleUser.accessToken
          );
          // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
          firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then(function(result) {
              console.log('user signed in ');

             
              if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                firebase
                  .database()
                  .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
                  .set({
                    gmail: result.user.email,
                    profile_picture: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.picture,
                    first_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
                    last_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.family_name,
                    created_at: Date.now()
                  })
                  .then(function(snapshot) {
                    // console.log('Snapshot', snapshot);
                  });
              } else {
                firebase
                  .database()
                  .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
                  .update({
                    last_logged_in: Date.now()
                  });
              }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              // Handle Errors here.
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
              // The email of the user's account used.
              var email = error.email;
              // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
              var credential = error.credential;
              // ...
            });
        } else {
          console.log('User already signed-in Firebase.');
        }
      }
    );
  };
const signInWithGoogleAsync = async() => {
  try {
    const result = await Google.logInAsync({
      behavior:"web",
      androidClientId: '762894301670-gt5nvlevp6i94bkglqj3h5b8dhfrrj9u.apps.googleusercontent.com' ,
      //iosClientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE,
      scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    });

    if (result.type === 'success') {
      
            onSignIn(result)
            
            
      return result.accessToken;
    } else {
      return { cancelled: true };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return { error: true };
  }
}
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Button
     title="Sign In with Google"
     onPress={() =>signInWithGoogleAsync() }
     />
   </View>
  )
}

export default LogInScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }

})
```

Navigator

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
//import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
//import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import LogInScreen from '../Navigation/Screens/LogInScreen'
import HomeScreen from '../Navigation/Screens/HomeScreen'
import CreateAlertScreen from '../Navigation/Screens/CreateAlertScreen'
import AlertScreen from '../Navigation/Screens/AlertScreen'
import {firebase} from '../firebase/config'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MainStackNavigation = () =>{

  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data()
            setLoading(false)
            setUser(userData)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false)
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    });
  }, []);
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator/>
    )
  }

  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator >
      { user? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="AlertScreen" component={AlertScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="CreateAlertScreen" component={CreateAlertScreen}/>
          </>
        ) : (
           <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogInScreen}/>
        )}
     </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}
export default MainStackNavigation
```

Comment: You can try to use navigation.navigate("Home") in your signInWithGoogleAsync function

Comment: Its still redirecting to the LogIn Screen